# send a HTTPRequest to a controller from a class in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller and my requirement is to call a method of controller from a new class. 
Suppose this is my method

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Timed
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadProductsRailWidget/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getProductsRailWidget(){
    /////some code here 
    return modelAndView;
    }
```

and I want to call this method from

```
public class TestRepeat {

@Timed
public void repeat() {
    System.out.println("Called... AT :: " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

}

let me know how can I do this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of your controller from your class and invoke the method. But this will not give you any of the wired components, as this is a regular way of calling classes and its no advisable. 
TestController tC = new TestController();
tC.getProductsRailWidget();

The other way is get the controller from ctx.getBean("");

Comment: I tried TestController tC = new TestController(); but there are some other components that are autowired. I am not getting that, and that's required.

Comment: is there any way I can call this using HTTPRequest from other class like we call from jsp.

Comment: try TestController tc = ApplicationContext.getBean(TestController.class);